# JSON ajax response not rendering in html

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to retrieve every five seconds any friends who are online for a user but jquery is not display the json result(s) in html, even though a json string being returned contains the names of friend(s). I checked the console and even did an alert box to test and it works, I just cannot get it to display inside a paragraph tag.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    function buildOnlineFriendList() {
        $.getJSON("/members/friends/get-friends-online", function() {
        }).done(function(msg) {
            if (msg.friends == "" || msg.friends == undefined) {
                $('#friends').html("No friends are online.");
            } else {
                var friendNames = msg.friends.join('<br />');
                $('#friends').html(friendNames);
            }
        }).fail(function(msg) {
            $('#friends').html(msg.message);
        });
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        buildOnlineFriendList();
    }, 5000);

     buildOnlineFriendList();
});
```

and the html:

```
<!-- right column -->
<div class="w3-col m2">
    <div class="w3-card-2 w3-round w3-white">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <p class="w3-center">Friends Online</p>
            <p class="w3-left" id="friends"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- end right column -->
</div>
```

I know I'm probably doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out, as other features that use the same code work. I can try and offer more information if my question is unclear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what return `console.log(msg.friends)` ?

Comment: it returns ["jimmy"]

Comment: Ok second answer is ok. Now the var `friendNames ` what return ?

Comment: I'm looking at your code and I see absolutely nothing wrong.  Is it possible you have another element on the page with `id="friends"`?

Comment: it returns jimmy.

Comment: No. The id must be unique

Comment: ah yes, I just realized I had the same id twice, I'm sorry. :(

Comment: I know the ID must be unique which is why I posed the question.  I'm wondering if there's another element with the same ID and he's applying the value to the wrong element.

Comment: in this case try to assign manually `$('#friends').html('this is a test');`

Comment: yes, I had the same id used twice, just found it, thanks :)

Comment: Yep, the dreaded ID collision.  We've all been there at one point or another causing hours of frustration.  Glad that helped you.  Btw, good job on a well formed question.